# Should I not use url_for() to point to my static files in Flask?

Tags: python, performance, flask

In the [Static Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files) section of the Flask [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) guide. It states:

> Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where
>   the CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server
>   is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can
>   do that as well.

Does this mean that I should not use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='styles.css')}}">
```

In my app once I'm in production? My app is used internally at work, so it's not getting a ton of traffic, but it is used throughout the day.

Should I switch it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
```

Will the performance be better?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not what it's saying at all.

`url_for('static', filename='...')` generates links to static assets. When using the dev server, Flask serves the files, but it's inefficient. In production, you would tell your web server to serve everything under `/static` directly, rather than letting Flask handle it. That doesn't change what the urls are, though, just where they are handled. Building urls is relatively fast and is unlikely to be what's taking time in your application.